# Restoring expected UTF-8 European characters in MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-5.6

I have a "keyword" column that contains German, Spanish, French specific characters but appear incorrectly. How can I rectify it?

E.g. `fÃ¤hre` appears whereas I need it to show `fähre`

When checking the `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` and `COLLATION_NAME` I get `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_general_ci` respectively.

I've tried:

- `ALTER TABLE gsSearchAnalyticsTest
  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;`
- `ALTER TABLE gsSearchAnalyticsTest
  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`
- `CONVERT(CAST(keyword as BINARY) USING utf8mb4) as keyword_new`
- `CONVERT(keyword USING utf8mb4) as keyword_new`
- Creating a new table and using `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` and `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (this gives me a `Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes` error even though biggest `VARCHAR` is `VARCHAR(255)`)

The only thing that works is this:
`REPLACE(keyword, 'Ã¤', 'ä') as keyword_new` but surely there is an easier way rather than doing a replace for all these type of characters?

If it's too much work in MySQL, then open to solutions using Python where efficient?

Comment: Obviously if the character set is already utf8mb4, your `ALTER TABLE` statements would have no effect. And collation simply refers to how text is sorted, not displayed. Probably the data was stored incorrectly and your best bet would be to re-insert it correctly. How are you accessing the data?

Comment: `fÃ¤hre` is what I would excpect a UTF8 string to look like if it was converted to a *single-byte codepage. That's exactly what `fähre` looks like if it gets converted to ASCII. The data looks OK. The problem is how it's displayed

Comment: @miken32 - accessing via sql editor.
@PanagiotisKanavos - what to do in order to get it to display `fähre` and not `fÃ¤hre`? Convert to ASCII?

Comment: I don't know what that is. Try accessing from the `mysql` command line, this will give you a better idea of how the data is stored. (Assuming you have a UTF-8 terminal encoding!)